# How do I insulate my basement wall to meet the R requirement

Tags: insulation

I am in the process of finishing my basement. If I read the 2021 energy codes, I need to meet a requirement of R19. Does that mean I have to build 2x6 walls.

Comment: Above the basement yes, but the basement walls will support the house, so you only need the depth(5.5 inches) or more.  2x4s placed at 2 inches away from the wall will work.  Usually the amount of the wall above the frost level needs the insulation more than below the frost level.